# Variable Names In JSON List Followed By Object Details

Tags: java, json, list

I've got a curious JSON to work with that I need to be able to map to a Java object. The environment I'm working in doesn't have access to Guava's Multimap (if that even is a solution), and I've considered being able to extend some sort of base class with a variable class name (if that is even possible), but I'm out of my depth on this one.

What sort of Java object allows lists of objects with unique, varying references to the same object class?

Here's a sample of the JSON I'm working with, I've confirmed it's a valid JSON via JSON formatter:

`{
    "apple1":{
        "orchard":"green groves orchard",
        "zipcode": 34567,
        "speciesId": 12345,
        "applePickedNumber": 6437896,
        "knownProducts":{
            "green grove apple butter":{
                "productId":"ABC123456789",
                "manufacturer":"red barn cannery",
                "shipper":"hermes shipping"
            }
        }
    },
    "apple2":{
        "orchard":"fair pastures orchard",
        "zipcode": 34567,
        "internalSpeciesId": 10001,
        "speciesId": 23456,
        "applePickedNumber": 145,
        "knownProducts":{}
    }
}`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I didn't get what's the issue? this is not also a list of object in json, this is an object with has got 2 object with filed name apple1, apple2 of type probably Apple.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have been more descriptive. Apple1 and Apple2 are just examples. Presumably the list could continue further, just like the list "knownProducts" could continue further. The names are dynamic and not associated to a specific variable name. To be more specific, "apple1" and "apple2" are not defined by name in the overarching JSON class, just as "green grove apple butter" is not defined as a variable name within the "knownProducts" list, rather the name seems to be a reference to the object within the list, rather than having an index reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is probably `Object[]` and `Map<String,Object>`.  But if you are going to map your JSON to types like that, then you should probably abandon the idea of mapping, and just use the `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` types.

Mappings only really work if the JSON conforms to a fixed "schema" with fixed attribute names.  You can't map JSON to POJO classes if the attribute names keep changing.

Answer (score 0):

Example when using Jackson. Define other attributes in Object class

```
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeRef
            = new TypeReference<>() {
    };
    HashMap<String, Object> result = objectMapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
```